# keep span div aside in small browser

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap2

```
<div class='span-4'>
     menu list
</div>
<div class='span-8'>
    <div>
         some test 
    </div>
</div>
```

If I changed the browser size to small, right div is comming  under the `span4`.
When The width of browser is around '1000px' .

I would like to keep left div and right div aside until around 600px.

How can I set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes in [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) 2.x are just `span4` and `span8`. Take a look at [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem).